# Can't be able to create a laravel project after done all this

Tags: php, laravel, web, command-line, composer-php

When i type composer, npm, node 
everything works fine
But when I type laravel it shows 'laravel is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

when I type echo $PATH
it prints "$PATH"

I wanna create a new laravel project, is there anything i missed when installing laravel? how can I fix this Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try install from composer

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel project-name
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Download [composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/).
Follow these steps:

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === 'a5c698ffe4b8e849a443b120cd5ba38043260d5c4023dbf93e1558871f1f07f58274fc6f4c93bcfd858c6bd0775cd8d1') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

Verify with `composer -v`

2) Then [install Laravel 6](http://composer%20global%20require%20laravel/installer). Run

```
composer global require laravel/installer
```

3) Once installed, the `laravel new` command will create a fresh Laravel installation in the directory you specify. E.g. `laravel new blog`

4) Directories within the `storage` and the `bootstrap/cache` directories should be writable by your web server or Laravel will not run.

5) `php artisan key:generate`

6) `php artisan serve`

Hope it helps. Cheers!